# Tomcat не видит директорию с файлами ресурсов

Tags: java, jsp, servlet, tomcat, ресурсы

Всем привет, возникла проблема, я пытаюсь на удаленный сервер выложить свое приложение, но на сервере при чтении из файла Tomcat кидает `FileNotFoundException`, т.к. не может найти папку с ресурсами (в которой лежит JSON файл с нужными параметрами).

На `localhost` проблемы нет, папка с ресурсами лежит в `C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\resources\` .

В сервлете обращаюсь по пути:

```
JsonReader reader = new JsonReader(new FileReader("resources/users.json"));
```

На удаленном сделал аналогично, закинул в папку с Tomcat`ом - не работает. Пробовал в разные директории добавлять - тоже. Подскажите по какому пути папку с ресурсами добавлять или в каких это конфигах можно поправить?

Comment: Вы деплоите проект из war архива?

Comment: да, я просто закидываю war на сервер, а папку с ресурсами руками просто закидываю

Comment: Может папку с ресурсами в варник запаковать?

Comment: Попробовал добавлять папку с ресурсами в  `src/main/webapp` и упаковывать в `war`, проблема осталась, причем у меня есть аналогичная папка `src/main/webapp/jsp` в которой у меня лежат мои `.jsp` файлы и в коде я к ним обращаюсь без проблем. Пример: `RequestDispatcher requestDispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("/jsp/login.jsp");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Положите папку в `src`, затем вы сможете вытягивать файл с помощью

```
JsonReader reader = new JsonReader(
new FileReader(
 new InputStremReader(
  this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("resources/users.json")));
```

Comment: На хостинге структура проектов другая, там нет папки `src` , root папкой является `http/...`.  Мой проект лежит `http/webapps/myproj/...`

Comment: Там и не нужна эта папка, файлы из этой папки сопируются в папку `classes`.