# Чтение файлов внутри зависимого jar

Tags: java, исключения, jar

Имеется jar-файл, в котором в папке с ресурсами лежит набор файлов. В одном из классов пытаюсь вычитать определенный файл:

```
TestClass.class.getClassLoader()
          .getResource("xml/text1.xml").getFile();
```

После этого я пытаюсь подключить это в jar в другой war, и в нем обращаюсь к классу, в котором вычитываются файлы способом, описанным выше, и получаю `NullPointerException`. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Почитайте [этот ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/765256/204271), должен помочь.

Answer (score 0):

У вас относительный путь к файлу задан. Чтобы подключить `jar` к `war` нужен класслоадер который может подключить `jar` к `war`. Поскольку вы пользуетесь стандартным класслоадером, то вы не можете подключить `jar` к `war`. Простое перемещение в папку архива ничего не дает.

Чтобы загружать ресурсы вам надо положить файл в папку с ресурсами и открывать поток для чтения сожержимого файлов. Например как это сделано [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/824690/204920).